# Siding issue or painting issue?

Tags: painting, exterior, siding

On the southern exposure side of my home, it appears either the siding is damaged or the paint has dissipated in spots. I’m not sure which. The rest of the home is a shade darker and doesn’t have any spots like that looks this.  The home was last painted in 2018, I bought it in 2019. Any ideas? I don’t want to waste a contractors time when trying to get bids to fix it.
Thanks for your time!

[image: eye level spot]

[image: siding looks rough]

Comment: It looks like the surface was not cleaned properly before the paint was applied. And the paint is falling off at those places. You just have to ask a painter.